# DreamFactory how to disable wrapper "resource" in docker container

Tags: docker, dreamfactory

I'm using DreamFactory REST API in a Docker container and I need to disable wrapper "resource" in payload. How can I achieve this?

I have replaced the following in all of these four files:

```
opt/bitnami/dreamfactory/.env-dist
opt/bitnami/dreamfactory/vendor/dreamfactory/df-core/config/df.php
opt/bitnami/dreamfactory/installer.sh
bitnami/dreamfactory/.env

DF_ALWAYS_WRAP_RESOURCES=true
```

with:

```
DF_ALWAYS_WRAP_RESOURCES=false
```

but this doesn't fix my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The change you describe is indeed the correct one as found in the [DreamFactory wiki](http://wiki.dreamfactory.com/DreamFactory/API#The_Resource_Wrapper). Therefore I suspect the configuration has been cached. Navigate to your DreamFactory project's root directory and run this command:

```
$ php artisan config:clear
```

This will wipe out any cached configuration settings and force DreamFactory to read the `.env` file in anew. Also, keep in mind you *only* need to change the `.env` file (or manage your configuration variables in your server environment). Those other files won't play any role in configuration changes.

Comment: ok but how can I make a $ php artisan config:clear  in a docker container ? I have already made a clear cache from UI interface but without luck

Comment: Hi @LucaFolin to run a command inside your container you'll typically execute `docker exec -i -t container_name /bin/bash`. Once the terminal has opened, you can navigate to the DreamFactory root directory and clear the cache. However I am confused though, did you modify the `.env` settings and then redeploy your container? Or did you enter Docker container via aforementioned approach and edit it there?

Comment: You are right. With this command it works: 

docker exec -i -t container_name dreamfactory php /opt/bitnami/dreamfactory/artisan cache:clear

docker exec -i -t container_name dreamfactory php /opt/bitnami/dreamfactory/artisan config:clear